# Why won't Scipy's wavefile.py from scipy.io open a wave file?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to build an audio frequency to visible waveform converter *a la* synesthesia, but I'm getting a lovely little error:

```
/Users/nathanielastudillo/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py:172: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-c1948c42b069>", line 5, in <module>
    rate, audio = wavfile.read('3 - Headache.wav')

  File "/Users/nathanielastudillo/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 166, in read
    data = _read_data_chunk(fid, comp, noc, bits, mmap=mmap)

  File "/Users/nathanielastudillo/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 71, in _read_data_chunk
    data = numpy.fromstring(fid.read(size), dtype=dtype)

TypeError: data type "<i3" not understood
```

Truly pleasant. I did a little digging through numpy's dtype [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) and discovered that the non-data chunk that wavfile.py is having a hard time chewing on is a little-endian signed integer, presumably 3 bytes long, going by @mgilson's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080279/how-do-i-create-a-numpy-dtype-that-includes-24-bit-integers).

It seems that numpy doesn't want to play with a 3-byte little-endian signed integer, for whatever reason. I thought to use the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595928/issues-with-scipy-io-wave-file-processing-after-applying-fourier-transforms), but I can't even load the file. Would it make sense to try to hack together a modified version of wavefile.py? Does anyone have an idea of how I can work around this? My implementation, borrowing from [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/elegant-scipy/9781491922927/ch04.html#), is:

```
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy.io.wavfile

M=1024
rate, audio = wavfile.read('3 - Headache.wav')

freqs, times, spect = signal.spectrogram(audio, fs=rate, window='hanning',
                                  nperseg=1024, noverlap=M - 100,
                                  detrend=False, scaling='spectrum')
```

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: If the WAV file uses 24 bit data, [scipy can not read it](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1930).  You can try [wavio](https://pypi.org/project/wavio/), a small Python library that I wrote.  It is a wrapper of the Python standard `wave` library that returns the data as a numpy array.

Comment: How about using e.g. librosa or one of a dozen of other specialised audio libraries? If you know scipy has inherent problems with this data type...

Comment: I'll give wavio & librosa a try. Will report back when I've got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy simply cannot read the 24 bit WAV I'm trying to use. Thanks @WarrenWeckesser for the comment.